# Showing value from NSArray on the basis of other NSArray

Tags: objective-c, nsarray

(My english is not good).

**I have two NSArray.**

EXAMPLE:
     **1st NSArray** is storing

```
NSArray category= { ID:1,Name:Category1;ID:2, Name: Category2;ID:3, Name:Category3;}
```

**2nd NSArray** is storing

```
 NSArray product= {cat_ID:1, Category-Name:Category1, product_ID:1, Name: Banana;
                cat_ID:1, Category-Name:Category1, product_ID:2, Name: apple;
                cat_ID:1, Category-Name:Category1, product_ID:3, Name: berry;
                cat_ID:2, Category-Name:Category2, product_ID:4, Name: cantaloupe;
                cat_ID:2, Category-Name:Category2, product_ID:5, Name: elderberry;
                cat_ID:2, Category-Name:Category2, product_ID:6, Name: ginger;
                cat_ID:2, Category-Name:Category2, product_ID:7, Name: watermelon;
                cat_ID:3, Category-Name:Category3, product_ID:8, Name: xigua;
                cat_ID:3, Category-Name:Category3, product_ID:9, Name: avocado;
                cat_ID:3, Category-Name:Category3, product_ID:10, Name: basil;
                cat_ID:3, Category-Name:Category3, product_ID:11, Name: alfalfa;
                cat_ID:3, Category-Name:Category3, product_ID:12, Name: blackcurrant;}
```

All i want is if category name (i mean 1st NSArray category.name) is equals to 2nd NSArray's category name (i mean product.Category-Name) then print all product name.
 **Example:   category.name==** Category1;  then result will be **Product.Name = Banana, Apple, Berry;**

How to do this?

Comment: Please write in complete syntax... not in algo or pseudocode

Comment: this is a `NSDictionary`

Comment: sorry, i didn't get you. My question is if in product array has a category's name, i mean if product category.category-name = product.category-name then print product's who has a category-name.

Comment: @ShivanRaptor can u give me a little suggestion code, i don't know how to do?

Comment: You can use keyPath or NSPredicateFilter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your json-like notation, we will assume that key value pairs in "{...}" are NSDictionary objects. And you have an array of said NSDictionary objects, "[{...},{...},...]"

To get the products for a given category:

```
NSString *category = @"Category1";
NSArray *result = [NSArray array];
for (NSDictionary *dic in products) {
    if ([[dic objectForKey:@"Category-Name"] isEqualToString: category])
        result = [result arrayByAddingObject: [dic objectForKey: @"Name"] ];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you not to make Array for this kind of logic.

You should use NSDictionary/NSMutableDictionary.

Then you can filter easily by NSPredicateFilter.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this task in compact way by using `NSPredicate`

```
NSString *selectedCategory = @"Category1";

//filter array by category using predicate
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"Category-Name == %@", selectedCategory];

NSArray *filteredArray = [product filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
```

or just follow my blog [rajneesh071.blogspot.in](http://rajneesh071.blogspot.in/2012/10/predicates.html) for more info

Comment: mmm, ok thank you, i'll try this code and follow your blog too