# NSpredicate to filter the Array of Elements that has substrings

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, nsarray, nspredicate

I have written NSPredicate to filter the elements .

```
-(void)filterResult:(NSMutableArray*)array
{
    search=TRUE;
    filteredCategoryList=[[NSArray alloc]init];


    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"roles beginsWith %@ ||     UserResponseDetails IN %@ ",array,array];
    filteredCategoryList = [MembersList filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate]; 
    [filteredCategoryList retain];
}
```

The Problem is I am getting one of the  string like "sample;Example" in Roles and others are single string. How to write the Predicate condition to get the Element for Sample,Example,sample and Example. 
.

Comment: follow http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13541371/remove-objects-using-nspredicate/13542899#13542899

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13717735/showing-value-from-nsarray-on-the-basis-of-other-nsarray/13720280#13720280

Comment: This link doesnot answered me

Comment: get all object of roles == sample... then from this array filter roles==sample;Example

Comment: and may be this will help u http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13984846/how-to-join-two-strings-for-nspredicate-ie-firstname-and-lastname

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got a solution that I have to use 'contains' keyword instead of 'beginswith' in the predicate.