# How to join two strings for NSPredicate, ie firstname and lastname

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, nsstring, nspredicate

I have a `Person` Object which has two `NSString` properties; `firstName and lastName`.
I'm currently using an `NSPredicate` like so:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(firstName contains[cd] %@) OR (lastName contains[cd] %@)", searchText, searchText];
```

So, for example, say I'm searching for the name `"John Smith"`. In my search bar if I type `"Joh"`, then `John Smith` will appear as an option. This is good and fine, but if I type in `"John Sm"` it will go blank.

How can I join firstName and lastName in the `predicate` so if I was searching for `"John Sm"` then `John Smith` would still appear as an option.

I hope this makes sense. Thanks.

EDIT:
To add a bit more clarification, I'm using the `SearchDisplayController` delegate method:

```
-(void)filterContentForSearchText:(NSString *)searchText scope:(NSString *)scope;
```

and I'm using the `predicate` like so:

```
newArray = [personObjectArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
```

Comment: check here to give full information  https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/Articles/pSyntax.html

Comment: I've read that but I still don't understand how to do it.

Comment: You can better use dictionary or array such that we can implement it easily

Comment: NSArray* ar = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"on call", @"I'm on call", @"lala", @"On call", nil];
NSArray* filt = [ar filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"self like[c] 'on call'"]];
NSLog([filt description]);

//Output
"on call",
"On call"

Comment: I understand that, but I have a dynamic array of objects, of which I want to compare to the searchText with my two NSString properties from the object.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Try this,

```
NSString *text = @"John Smi";
NSString *searchText = [text stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]];

NSArray *array = [searchText componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];
NSString *firstName = searchText;
NSString *lastName = searchText;
NSPredicate *predicate = nil;

if ([array count] > 1) {
    firstName = array[0];
    lastName = array[1];
    predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(firstName CONTAINS[cd] %@ AND lastName CONTAINS[cd] %@) OR (firstName CONTAINS[cd] %@ AND lastName CONTAINS[cd] %@)", firstName, lastName, lastName, firstName];
} else {
    predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"firstName CONTAINS[cd] %@ OR lastName CONTAINS[cd] %@", firstName, lastName];
}

NSArray *filteredArray = [people filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
NSLog(@"%@", filteredArray);
```

Output:

```
(
        {
        firstName = John;
        lastName = Smith;
    }
)
```

Here text represents the searched text. The advantage with the above is, even if you pass `text = @"Smi Joh";` or `text = @"John ";` or `text = @" smi";` or `text = @"joh smi ";`, it will still show the above output.

Comment: Thank you works great except for one little issue. Say I'm in progress of typing "john " with the space, no results will appear until I start typing the last name, is there a way to still show John Smith with "john " in the search bar?

Comment: It is working fine for me with that too. I had tested with that before posting. I think you missed `NSString *text = @"john ";
    NSString *searchText = [text stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]];` I am sure you are not doing second line with the search text before you are filtering. Basically you need to remove any leading or trailing spaces while doing filtering or it will fail. So if you dont use second line, it will fail.

Comment: Ah yes it works fine, I had my firstName and lastName strings initialized to the wrong string. Sorry! But thank you, you've been a great help, I've spent ages trying to do this!

Comment: This does not work. As an example, if the user types John Smith blah blah, it will display John Smith. This is clear in the code as once the string components is over 1 ([array count] > 1) you still only use array[0] and array[1].

The best workaround would be to implement a method fullname in your object (or a category if it's a nsmanagedobject) and then use predicateWithBlock.

Answer (score 4):

The solution suggested above will not work with search strings that have more than two words. Here is a more thorough implementation in swift. This solution also allows for adding more fields on a record, if your goal is to implement a full text search across name, email, phone number, etc. In that case just update the NSPredicate to `OR newField CONTAINS[cd] %@` and be sure to add the extra $0 in the list of string replacements.

```
let searchText = search.stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet(NSCharacterSet.whitespaceCharacterSet())
let words = searchText.componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet(NSCharacterSet.whitespaceCharacterSet())
let predicates = words.map { NSPredicate(format: "firstName CONTAINS[cd] %@ OR lastName CONTAINS[cd] %@", $0,$0) }

let request = NSFetchRequest()
request.predicate = NSCompoundPredicate(type: NSCompoundPredicateType.AndPredicateType, subpredicates: predicates)
```

Comment: I'm late in some few years but. Your answer is the only answer that generically works

Comment: Seems to be the best answer!

Answer (score 1):

you can concatenate the fields into two common fields (firstLastName and lastFirstName )

```
- (NSString *)firstLastName {
      return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", self.firstName, self.lastName];
}

- (NSString *)lastFirstName {
      return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", self.lastName, self.firstName];
}
```

and then filter on this fields using 'contains[cd]'

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(firstLastName contains[cd] %@) OR (lastFirstName contains[cd] %@)" , self.searchBar.text, self.searchBar.text];
```