# How to apply predicate on fullname by combining firstname & lastname of the person entity in ios

Tags: core-data, ios8, nspredicate, nsfetchedresultscontroller, uisearchcontroller

I have "Person" entity in coredata with firstname, middlename & lastname. Now, i want to perform predicate search on fullname (combination of fn,mn,ln). Fullname is not an attribute of the entity. I am trying to fetch using nsfetchresultcontroller. E.g If I search "Jone Smith" it shows blank but if i search "John" then it shows records. Do reply.

Comment: did you find the anwser?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to join two strings for NSPredicate, ie firstname and lastname](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13984846/how-to-join-two-strings-for-nspredicate-ie-firstname-and-lastname)

Answer (score 0):

There could be various numbers of solutions. One of them is when we are trying to find a person with a full name, and we are not sure in what order the name user enter the name `Name and Lastname` or `Lastname and Name`.

Swift 5.0

```swift
// First we make components from incoming search text `searchText`
let text = searchText.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespaces)
let nameComponents = searchText.components(separatedBy: .whitespacesAndNewlines).compactMap { $0.isEmpty ? nil : $0 }

// Next we create predicate trying to find each component in name or lastname
let predicates = nameComponents.map { NSPredicate(format: "name contains[c] %@ OR lastname contains[c] %@", $0,$0) }

// Create `And` predicate
let andPredicate = NSCompoundPredicate.init(andPredicateWithSubpredicates: predicates)

// Use predicates in created `request`
request.predicate = andPredicate
```

Also, in the same way, there could be used middle name.

Answer (score -3):

Lets assume the field names are: fName, lName. Then the predicate will be:

```
NSPredicate* predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"fName = %@ and lName = %@", inputFName, inputLName)]
```

Comment: What is inputFName & inputLName? The snippet is incomplete. Please elaborate on it. My problem is when i try to search as "John" or "Smith", i get the results but when i type "John  " or "John Smith" i get no results. FN,Mn & LN should be combined. how to achieve that?

Comment: Why downvote? When you say it did not work could you please elaborate what happened?